# django - No return after call from another serializer

Tags: python, django

users/models.py

```
class GolferPhotoViewSet(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    GenericViewSet,):
    queryset = GolferPhoto.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GolferPhotoSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, GolferPhotoPermission)

    def get_queryset(self):
        data = self.kwargs
        if data.get("golfer_profile_pk"):
            if data.get("pk"):
                if self.request.query_params.get("photo_nickname"):
                    image_value = self.request.query_params.get("photo_nickname")
                    user = self.request.user.id
                    user_value = "GOLFER" + str(user)
                    return FileInfo.objects.get(
                        reference_value=user_value, image_nickname=image_value
                    )

                obj = GolferPhoto.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
                self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
                return self.queryset.filter(pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
            else:
                obj = GolferPhoto.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["golfer_profile_pk"])
                self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
                return self.queryset.filter(
                    golfer_profile_id=self.kwargs["golfer_profile_pk"]
                )
        else:
            return super().get_queryset()
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/golfer-profile/1/golfer-photos/3?photo_nickname=MAIN

I'd like to return one object from a model called [Fileinfo],
but it says [{"detail":"Not Found"} in postman.

```
    instance = FileInfo.objects.get(
    reference_value=user_value, image_nickname=image_value
)
serializer = FileInfoSerializer(instance)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Even if I put it in the serializer, it doesn't work out the way I want it to, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered a similar issue. If possible share how you have registered your URL's. eg.

```
router.register(r"", UserViewSet, "all_users")
router.register(r"devices", LoginDeviceViewSet, "devices")
```

This will trigger a detail not found error.

Whereas changing this to:

```
router.register(r"devices", LoginDeviceViewSet, "devices")
router.register(r"", UserViewSet, "all_users")
```

resolves the issue.